# Remember username and password in Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome

For some reason Chrome 71 will not remember my username and password for certain sites. The usual "Do you want Google Chrome to save your password for this site" does not appear and I have to type my credentials every time.

This only happens for some sites. Unfortunately for this spesific site I cannot share the URL because it is an internal work URL.

The official [documentation](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95606?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) does not have any explanation for this.

[image]

**Edit**: The login prompt is not a regular HTML form but rather what is known as "[**Basic access authentication**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)".

I still have not found a way to save this information in Chrome. There might not be any way as this standard is pretty old and very few sites use it, often corporate intranet sites.

Comment: Are you sure that the login form does not include `autocomplete=off` for the password field in the HTML?

Comment: This is not a regular HTML `<form>`

Comment: Then what is it?

Comment: You state this is an issue with more than one site, but the example you want to use is an internal site? Do you have an example of a public page? Otherwise, talk to your company IT.

Comment: You could try using a password manager as a workaround (Lastpass for example).

Comment: Password managers do not apply to Basic Authentication.